# Can I connect an external hard drive to a USB port of NSA 320 and make it available over the network?

Tags: hard-drive, nas

I am planning to buy a ZyXEL NSA 320 box. Can I connect an external hard drive to the USB port of the NSA 320 and make it available over the network – without having internal drives?

Comment: Why would you not want to use the internal drives?

Comment: i do not want to buy them now. Wait for black friday. I do have 3TB external USB Hard drive

Comment: ah this makes sense now that I've read more about the product and found that it doesn't ship with drives :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product details [here](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822336015) seem to indicate that it will support external drives:

> - File system support
>
> Internal HDD: EXT4
>
> External HDD: NTFS, EXT2, EXT3, FAT32, ReiserFS, XFS

Here is [a review](http://www.amazon.com/review/R3QP1W0X2X9NN6) with some more clues...

> 2. Other NAS backup strategies backup drives to externals as files when schduling "jobs". They are accessible from your computer using
>      the external drives if the NAS fails. This box does scheduled jobs in
>      a proprietary format, so you would have to by another Zyxel to
>      restore. There ARE two ways around some of this: A: A setting for the
>      front button will let you backup one of your shares and mirror it to
>      an external drive. You cannot schedule this though. B: You can use
>      drag-and-drop or software on your computer to cause files to
>      move/mirror to an external drive as files. BUT, since you are passing
>      through your CPU, it is slower and bound by that computer remaining
>      on.

Honestly, it's not looking like you'll want to waste time with this...